# Is it possible to run Tor before windows login?

Tags: windows, transparent-proxy, server-administration

I have set a computer at my home as Tor proxy server that pass the traffic of my internet users through the Tor network. Whenever my server restart I have to manually login my server to let Tor expert bundle get started. Is there any way that I could run Tor as a windows service or run it before windows login?

Comment: There's a FAQ on this at https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#NTService. But I'm not enough of a Windows geek to massage that into an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on mirimir's comment, To install Tor as a service, you can simply run:

```
tor --service install
```